# Solving a Quadratic Inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics, fractions, quadratic-forms

> Solve the inequality:
>   $$\dfrac{x-1}{x^2-4x+3}<1.$$

I cancelled the $x-1$ from the numerator and the denominator and I obtained: $$\frac{x-4}{x-3}.$$
 Thus, the answer that I got was $$x \in(3,4).$$
 But according to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x-1)%2F(x%5E2-4x%2B3)%3C1) answer should be $$x \in(4,\infty)\cup(1,3)\cup(-\infty,1).$$

What is the best method to solve this inequality and where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You cannot simply **cancel** the $x-1$: although the two terms are indeed algebraically equivalent, the two as functions are not the same, as before the cancellatoon $1$ is not in the domain (i.e it makes no sense to evaluate the fraction at that point as you  should divide by zero). Besides thet, I would re-do the calculation from the very start

Comment: @b00nheT of course you can cancel. But even after cancellation you will not add 1 to  the domain.

Comment: Michael's answer addresses this point clearly. We can cancel but only after taking the condition $x\ne0$ @b00nheT

Comment: @miracle173 you are mistaken. See the other answers

Comment: @b00nheT all the answers cancel. Do you want to say one has to determine the domain of the function at first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's
$$\frac{1}{x-3}<1$$ and $x\neq1$ or
$$1-\frac{1}{x-3}>0$$ or
$$\frac{x-4}{x-3}>0,$$ which by the intervals method   gives
$x<3$ or $x>4$ and  with $x\neq1$ we got the answer:
$$(-\infty,1)\cup(1,3)\cup(4,+\infty)$$

Comment: Okay, how would you solve that?

Comment: @Abcd I added something. See now.

Comment: Understood :) .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must check the condition: $x \neq 1$ and $x\neq 3$.

So, you have $$\frac{x-1}{(x-1)(x-3)} < 1,$$ or $$\frac{1}{x-3} < 1.$$

Now, you have

Case 1: $x-3 < 0$ or $x < 3$, but you have $x \neq 1$, then $x < 1$ or $1 < x <3$.

Case 2: $x - 3 > 0$ and $x - 3 > 1$, then $x > 4$.

Answer (score 0):

The quotient $\dfrac{x-1}{x^2-4x+3}$ is defined for all $x$ with $x \ne 1$ and $x \ne 3$. For those $x$ we have

$\dfrac{x-1}{x^2-4x+3}=\dfrac{1}{x-3}$.

For the inequality $\frac{1}{x-3}<1$ you have to distinguish the cases

$x>3$ and $x<3$. Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{(x-1)}{(x-3)(x-1)} < 1$$

Hence $x \neq 1$ and $x \neq 3$.

$$\frac{1}{(x-3)} < 1$$

Multiply $(x-3)^2$ throughout.

$$(x-3) < (x-3)^2$$

$$0< (x-3)(x-3-1)$$

$$0< (x-3)(x-4)$$

Hence $x \in \left((-\infty, 3) \cup (4, \infty)\right) \setminus\{ 1,3\}$

Hence $x \in (-\infty, 1) \cup (1,3) \cup (4, \infty)$.